# Why does a std::variant compile with begin and end iterators?

Tags: c++, std-variant

It seems that the compiler should be able to catch the fact that std::variant doesn't have iterator methods, but it seems that my code compiles with no problem (even if I randomly make up methods or member variables for the variant), but it crashes at runtime (rightfully so). Can someone shed some light on why this code compiles?

Note: this isn't blocking progress because now I'm using std::visit, but it would be nice to know why this is compiling.

I have tried using different variant patterns and they all compile. See code examples. You can pop this in to cppreferences, or godbolt and it should compile with C++17 flags or greater

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>

template<typename K, typename V>
//using var_maps = std::variant<std::map<K,V>, std::multimap<K,V> >;
//using var_maps = std::variant<std::list<int>, std::list<float> >;
using var_maps = std::variant<int, float>;

template <typename K, typename V>
void flat( const var_maps<K,V>& vmap)
{
    //for(auto bIter = vmap.bexxxgin(), eIter = vmap.end(); bIter != eIter;
    for(auto bIter = vmap.begin(), eIter = vmap.end(); bIter != eIter;
      bIter = vmap.upper_bound( bIter->first )  )
      {

      }
}
```

My initial case was with maps, but it effectively compiles with anything. Additionally I can randomly replace begin() to any other word and it still compiles. I know the right way to do this is with visits. I am inevitably trying to have one function that handles both map and multimap and transform it to another data structure.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles, because `begin()` and `end()` are dependent names - they depend on the function template arguments, so their lookup is postponed until the `flat` template instantiation. But it is never instantiated!

If you add the following, your code won't compile anymore:

```
int main () {
     &flat<int, int>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It "compiles" because the function is a template. No code is generated here and beyond basic syntax checking no complete checking can be done when the template is parsed.

This is because the compiler does not know whether the `var_maps<K,V>` contains `begin()` or not. There could be specializations.

You will receive the error when you instantiate `var_maps`, i.e. use `var_maps` with concrete types `K` and `V`.

Comment: I see, so everything that is ever templated methods are postponed until instantiation (regardless of type). What I don't understand is that std::variant would never have a begin and end iterator, right? When would this actually work? I dont think I can place any type in K and V that will make variant have a begin and end method?